# Shared Memory Segment of a global Struct in "On demand" Server

Tags: c, struct, tcp, server, shared-memory

I have to create for academic purpose an "On-Demand Server" that is based on the TCP protocol. The client each time sends a KEY and a VALUE that I have to store them in a global struct using two functions.

**EDIT:**
If a **client** asks for **put** I have to store in the **struct** the **key** and the **value** that the client send to the server. If the client asks for **get** I have to search in the struct and **return** to the client the **Value**. Since I use fork each time a new client connects and writes/read in the struct it is impossible for the other children(clients) to see the changes that the first on makes in the struct so I had to make the struct visible to every child. But that does not happen for some reason.

Bellow is the code of my attempt.

**NOTE:** The parameters of functions put() and get() cannot be changed.

My solution does not work and I am trying to find out why! I am very new to "shared memory" things and I hope I can find some help here.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you receive an error?

Comment: @BenSteffan If a client asks for put I have to store in the struct the key and the value that the client send to me. if the client asks for get I have to return to the client the Value. Since I use fork each time a new client connects and writes/read in the struct it is impossible for the other children(clients) to see the changes that the first on makes in the struct so I had to make the struct visible to every child. I tried the above but the clients cannot see any change!

Comment: @BenSteffan I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a variety of misunderstandings on how share memory segments works.

1.You are creating shared memory for the struct, but not for the struct's elements. You need also to attach `keyvalue.keys` and `keyvalue.values` to a shared memory segment. Remember that in C languge a struct is like a pointer to its elements. So you are creating a memory segment only for this "pointer" (someone can correct me if i am wrong )

2.Every new child process that is being created has its own memory map. So you have to attach manually every new process to this shared memory segments of your struct manually every time. Once you are done you can de-attached the child process. (and here comes your next logic issue)

3.If i get it right, in these line of code

```
        close(acceptfd);
}//while(1) end
```

the father is deataching himself from the sharedMemory segment. That will result into new child processes have no shared memory segments to attach to. Since you are creating a server and you want this to run 'forever' , if you want to de-attach father process from the shared memory segment, you can only do it with a system call on SIGINT. So right before CTRL+C, the function of SIGINT manipulation will also deatach the father from the sh.m. segment. If you ain't closing the segment, you can do it manually later through terminal.

Hope i helped somehow!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answered! I am wondering how can I attach keyvalue.keys and keyvalue.values to a shared memory segment?

Comment: `shmat` requires a pointer to work. So you need to have a call by reference towards your struct, in order to attach the struct and struct's elements into a shared memory segment. once this is done you can do something like keyvalue->key=shat(); to attach each elemt. Dont forget that you have to atach every process later manually there. 
I am surely mistaking some things my self, so read Beej's guide to shared memory if you haven't! http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/shm.html

Comment: Thank again! I will check the guide and I hope that it helps me.